# Why not leave Yomiyama?

Tags: another

In the anime *Another*, the town of Yomiyama is cursed with a calamity that causes the deaths of members of Class 3-3 and their family members living in the town.

This is obviously a big problem. **So why don't the members of 3-3 and their families switch schools?** Wouldn't that be a better choice than to risk death in Yomiyama?

Comment: presumably because once you've gotten in the class, there's no escaping the curse, even if you physically move away, as we have seen

Answer (score 2):

The deaths are tied to both members of class 3-3 and Yomiyama. My guess is that if you try to leave either class 3-3 or Yomiyama you'll be killed by doing so, rather than waiting for your turn to die through the normal means of the curse--one death every month.

This is mentioned in the show due to one of the character's deaths and on the [wiki](http://another.wikia.com/wiki/Deaths):

> [Aya Ayano](http://another.wikia.com/wiki/Aya_Ayano) - While leaving Yomiyama with her parents in their family car, a rock fell and hit the windshield, causing her father to lose control and drive off the mountain.

Comment: Not necessarily true – otherwise, how would Kouchi and his friends be able to travel to the beach in a neighboring city safely? Also, the person you mentioned was killed while leaving – but she hadn't quite left the city just yet. (thanks for the answer, though!)

Comment: Oh yeah. Then unfortunately there is no definitive answer to this, only speculation. For example, leaving with the intent of not coming back triggers a death. E.g. they're bound to Yomiyama and class 3-3 and any attempt to permanently leave triggers the curse.

Comment: All right. I'll see if I can do any more research to find the answer, I will post it if I discover anything with evidence. Thanks!

Comment: @Angelplayer Wouldn’t *leaving for the neighbouring town’s beach* be considered *coming back soon* while *leaving for good* is bad? The curse, being something supernatural, would know the difference — but it would have to act while the people are still within its jurisdiction, i.e. before the car left the town’s boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Kouichi asked this same question from Chibiki. Chibiki said consider it as a cellphone going out of range. The curse doesn't affect a person if the person goes out of city.